# text that should flow to next line does not increase parent box model

Tags: html, overflow, css

To start I am trying to log chat and have a somewhat easy time reading it (doesn't need to be pretty)
I have got most of this done with CSS but I have come into one small problem where if one chat line overflows, it will overflow onto the next chat line

[image: Text Overflow Issue]

How would I get the second line to be below the first text if it overflows?

I have tried using the CSS tag "overflow: auto;" and "overflow: scroll;" but both just put the text onto one line with scrollbars for each line that overflows which is not what I want.

Here is my HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <ul class="chat-lines">
            <div class="chat-line">

                <span class="timestamp"><small><!--timestamp-->00:00</small></span>

                <span class="badges">
                </span>

                <span style="color: #ff0000" class="from">username</span>
                <span class="colon">:</span>&nbsp;

                <span class="message">message message message message message message message
                message message message message message message message message
                message message message message message message message message message
                message message message message message message message message message
                message message message message message message message message message
                message message message message message message </span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-line">

                <span class="timestamp"><small><!--timestamp-->00:00</small></span>

                <span class="badges">
                </span>

                <span style="color: #ff0000" class="from">username</span>
                <span class="colon">:</span>&nbsp;

                <span class="message">message message message message message message message
                message message message message message message message message
                message message message message message message message message message
                message message message message message message message message message
                message message message message message message message message message
                message message message message message message </span>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my css.css file

```
body
{
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 13.33px;
    line-height: 17.33px;
    font: 14px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    display: block;
    background: rgb(0,0,0)!important;   
}
.chat-lines
{
    color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
    display: block;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 17.33px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 90%;
}
.chat-line
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0392157) 0px 1px 0px 0px inset;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0392157) 0px 1px 0px 0px inset;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 17px;
    line-height: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    word-break: break-word;
}
.chat-line:nth-child(2n)
{
  background-color:rgb(35,35,35);
}
.timestamp
{
    color: rgb(140,140,140);
    display: inline;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: auto;
}
.badges
{
    color: rgb(211,211,211);
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 19px;
    line-height: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 23px;
}
.badges: after
{
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0px;
}
.from
{
    color: rgb(255, 57, 183);
    display: inline;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-transform: none;
    width: auto;
}
.colon
{
    color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
    display: inline;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: auto;
}
wbr
{
    color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
    display: inline;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: auto;
}
.message
{
    color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
    display: inline;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the height for each of your 'chat-lines' to 17px. This doesn't let the element's height grow if the contents overflow. Instead use the min-height property.